# Controlling the animation of hidden property in UIStackView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistackview

I have a UIStackView element and i set `hidden = false` to its elements inside `UIView.animateWithDuration`.

The issue i am seeing is that the cells are showing from the bottom right corner and not from bottom center. Can i control this animation?

Comment: Do those cells appear at the right place without animation?